# Rice in a salt shaker

Tags: shabbat, yom-tov, borer-separating

Is there allowed to be rice in a salt shaker on shabbat or yom tov?

**Background:** I was under the impression that the answer to this question is no, as for something not to be considered בורר (separating), it needs to be immediate, by hand, and taking the good from the bad. This example lacks the middle one.

Another thought was that it would be מרקד (sifting) as that is what the salt shaker head is doing.

However, when I asked someone this question, they claimed that it was not a problem based on something in shemirat shabbat k'hilcheta (2nd edition) about coffee strainers (if I remember correctly, can't seem to find it now). The claim was also that even if this was not allowed on shabbat, it was not the case for yom tov

Comment: are you talking about having rice in with the salt to soak up the moisture?

Comment: Yes (needs padding).

Comment: Funny, I was about to say I think the shmirat shabbat talks about this case.

Comment: @DoubleAA, for some reason I thought this was a classic case of something that was not allowed, looking in shimirat shabbat again now EDIT: can't seem to find volume two right now, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shmiras Shabbos KeHilchasah (footnote to 3:60) quotes R' Shlomoh Zalman Aurbach that it is forbidden when the cover to the saltshaker is on.

3:60

> מותר לתת גרגירי אורז (לפני שבת, ומשום אסור מוקצה) בממליחה פחותה
>   ע"מ שיספגו את הלחות שבמלח, ובממליחה מכוסה טוב לא להוציא דרך המכסה שבה,
>   גם אם נשאר הרבה מלח מעורב בתוך האורז

footnote 179

> שמעתי מהגרש"ז
>   אוירבעך שליט"א [ז"ל] שאסור אפילו אם יש הרבה מלח כיון דאפשר דהו"ל כבורר
>   בנפה וכברה שאסור אפי` מעט, עכ"ד. ומ"מ יל"ע מהא דהערה קכה דלעיל

Comment: ba Interesting, especially considering GershonGold's answer. Does he mention a different psak there as well perhaps?

Comment: He writes in 3:60 that it's better not to do it. He writes in the footnote that R' Aurbach says it's forbidden, but questions him

Comment: Interesting. I will have to see it inside.

Comment: 3:60: מותר לתת גרגירי אורז (לפני שבת, ומשום אסור מוקצה) בממליחה פחותה ע"מ שיספגו את הלחות שבמלח, **ובממליחה מכוסה טוב לא להוציא דרך המכסה שבה**, גם אם נשאר הרבה מלח מעורב בתוך האורז ———— footnote 179: שמעתי מהגרש"ז אוירבעך שליט"א [ז"ל] שאסור אפילו אם יש הרבה מלח כיון דאפשר דהו"ל כבורר בנפה וכברה שאסור אפי` מעט, עכ"ד. ומ"מ יל"ע  מהא דהערה קכה דלעיל

Comment: (By the way, the "הערה קכה דלעיל" is quoted in Gershon Gold's article)

Comment: Wow did you type that or do you have a digital version?

Comment: I typed it, I don't think there is a digital version ([Hebrew keyboard](http://www.doitinhebrew.com/Translate/default.aspx?kb=IL+Hebrew+Phonetic))

Comment: I'm much obliged.

Comment: Would it make a difference if it was on yom tov or shabbat?

Comment: @soandos You are allowed to select on YT when the food is (1) normally eaten immediately after being selected and (2) when it is unusual for a lot of that food to be selected at once (4:2 quoting Shulchan Aruch 510:2 and Mishnah Brurah 510:5,7). I think it would be okay based on that, but CYLOR

Comment: @ba so this is borer and not meraked? or there is a similar exemption for meraked?

Comment: @soandos It's put in Shmiras Shabbos KeHilchasah on the chapter of borer, so I would assume so. But [sometimes](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=138&format=pdf) there's a very fine line.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.dinonline.org/2010/08/10/filter-on-faucet/

> Ayil Meshulash chapter 7 note 110 & Shemiras Shabbos 3:60 both say it
>   is permitted to use a salt shaker with rice inside on Shabbos.
>
> The reasoning is because the salt shaker is made solely for immediate
>   use, and therefore its use is not considered Derech Bereirah but
>   rather Derech Achilah.

Comment: I understand what the words mean, but to clarify, if there is any klee that does any sort of borer that will immediately go on food this is not an issue, because it is considered part of the way that we eat?

Comment: It sounds like that to me. However as usual CYLOR.

Comment: Mind reconciling this with the answer below?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be what the SSK is saying as quoted above - there is an important caveat that the salt-shaker not be closed.